# How do I get the third puzzle piece in Irreversible?

Tags: braid

In Braid, there is one (ok, many, but this question is only about one) puzzle piece that I cannot figure out how to obtain.

[image]

I have 2 keys with which I must open 3 locked doors.  The middle door and one of my two keys glow green, and thus are not affected by me reversing time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now, since the green key and the green door are unaffected by your time-reversal ability, once you use the green key, you cannot get it back, and once you open the green door, it won't close again.

You *can* however, get the normal key back by rewinding time and you can also make previously opened doors shut again, so be careful!

If you use the normal key on the green door, you can use the key twice because rewinding will give you back the key, but it won't close the door again.

Here's what you must do:

1. Get the green key and open the first door.
2. Get the normal key and DON'T REWIND. Rewinding will cause the door you have opened to slide shut again, but since the key you used was green, you won't get your key back, leaving you with 3 doors and only *one* key instead of two.
3. Use the normal key on the green door.
4. Rewind.  This will give you the key back, but leave the door open.
5. Use the key again, this time on the last door.
6. Profit!